# Automatically getting number and width of columns

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm having problems with a piece of code that automatically generates column number and width.

I'm getting everything done with this part of code, only thing that bothers me is that my grid is not used at 100%; there is small piece of grid that is unused and that makes report go crazy.

This is part of the code that does the job.

```
 procedure TForm1.NoScrollDBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  i: Integer;
  brkol: integer;
  sirina : Integer;
  width1: Integer;
begin
  width1 := 1;
  brkol:=-4;
  for i := 0 to NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    width1 := width1 + NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[i].Width + 1;
    if NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[i].Visible then
       brkol:=brkol +1;
  end;
  sirina:=(80 div brkol);
  if width1 < NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth - 8 then
  begin
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[0].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*2 div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[1].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*5 div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[2].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*10 div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[3].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*3 div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[4].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[5].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[6].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[7].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[8].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[9].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[10].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[11].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[12].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[13].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[14].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[15].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[16].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[17].Width:=(NoScrollDBGrid1.ClientWidth-11)*sirina div 100;
```

Comment: What type is your NoScrollDBGrid1 declared as, and which library does the grid come from?

Comment: It seems to me that if you calculate the width of each column than the last column should not be calculated but just take whatever is left. I cannot see that in you code or am I missing something ?

Comment: *'..... that makes report go crazy'* is quite a useless description of a problem. What is the expected behaviour and what is the observed behaviour?

Comment: Are you using a grid as a report? Why not use an actual reporting library?

Comment: @GuidoG im not sure its going to fix the problem but i guess i can try it out.

Comment: @TomBrunberg sorry, as i said grid is not used 100% , small piece of grid is unused and thas why panel's and checkboxes are not sorted as i wanted them to be. hope that makes it a bit better.

Comment: @JerryDodge not sure why but thats the way i have to do it. Kinda not my call.

Comment: I suspect the constant (on each cells drawing) recalculation/adjustment of column widths which triggers redrawing which potentially triggers re-adjustment which triggers ... Calculate/adjust column widths only once, e.g. in the forms OnCreate. Use the OndrawColumnCell only to fill in text represantation of the data.

Comment: And by the way is there any simpler way to get columns count and automatically width ?

Comment: Simpler than `NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns.Count` ? No.

Comment: Also, I still have no idea what your actual problem is. Now you speak about sorting panels and checkboxes. How is that related to column count and width in a grid. I'm afraid your question will be closed as unclear what you are asking, unless you edit it to be clearer and more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't *quite* answer your question, but should be enough to get you going.

The `CreateForm` event will create a `TNoScrollDBGrid` whose rightmost column stops short
of the righthand boundary of the grid's client area.

The Button1 click handler calls `GetDrawInfo` which shows how to retrieve the `DrawInfo` for the grid
(see `TGridDrawInfo` in `Grids.Pas`) and uses it to re-size the righthand column to
reach the RHS of the grid's client area.

`GetDrawInfo` also shows how to find the number of visible data columns - see `VisibleDataColumns`, allowing for the possible presence of the indicator column on the left.  The adjustment of the width of the rightmost column also takes into account whether there is an indicator column.

Btw, the grid's DrawCell event probably isn't a good place to change the layout of the grid as pointed out in a comment.

```
type
  TNoScrollDBGrid = Class(TDBGrid)  // Per Peter Below of TeamB
  private
    Procedure WMNCCalcSize( Var msg: TMessage );
     message WM_NCCALCSIZE;
  end;

 TForm1 = class(TForm)
   CDS1: TClientDataSet;
   DataSource1: TDataSource;
   Button1: TButton;
   procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 private
   procedure GetDrawInfo;
 protected
 public
   NoScrollDBGrid1 : TNoScrollDBGrid;
 end;
```

[...]

```
procedure TNoScrollDBGrid.WMNCCalcSize(var msg: TMessage);
const
 scrollstyles = WS_VSCROLL or WS_HSCROLL;
var
 style: Integer;
begin
 style := getWindowLong( handle, GWL_STYLE );
 If (style and scrollstyles) <> 0 Then
   SetWindowLong( handle, GWL_STYLE, style and not scrollstyles );
 inherited;
end;

type
  TMyGrid = class(TDBGrid);

procedure TForm1.GetDrawInfo;
var
  DrawInfo : TGridDrawInfo;
  i : Integer;
  Min,
  Max,
  R,
  NewLastCellWidth,
  VisibleDataColumns : Integer;
begin
  TMyGrid(NoScrollDBGrid1).CalcDrawInfo(DrawInfo);

  Min := 0;
  //  calculate the number of visible data columns, allowing for the
  //  indicator column, if there is one.
  VisibleDataColumns := DrawInfo.Horz.GridCellCount - DrawInfo.Horz.FixedCellCount;

  Max := VisibleDataColumns -1;
  if DrawInfo.Horz.FixedCellCount = 0 then
    Dec(Max);
  R := DrawInfo.Horz.FixedBoundary;

  //  Next, sum the widths of the data columns, *except*the right-most one   
  for i := Min to Max - 1 do begin
    Inc(R, NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[i].Width);
  end;

  if R < DrawInfo.Horz.FullVisBoundary then begin
    //  Work out what the width of the rightmost column needs to be
    //  to fill the grid
    NewLastCellWidth := DrawInfo.Horz.GridExtent - R;
    //  adjust this to allow for the width of the vertical lines between
    // the columns, etc
    NewLastCellWidth := NewLastCellWidth - 1 * (Max +1);
    NoScrollDBGrid1.Columns[Max].Width := NewLastCellWidth;
  end;
  Caption := IntToStr(R);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetDrawInfo;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: Integer;
  Field : TStringField;
const
  Fields = 4;
begin
  for i := 1 to Fields do begin
    Field := TStringField.Create(Self);
    Field.Size := 20;
    Field.FieldName := 'Field' + IntToStr(i);
    Field.Name := Field.FieldName;
    Field.FieldKind := fkData;
    Field.DataSet := CDS1;
  end;
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  CDS1.Insert;
  for i := 1 to Fields do begin
    CDS1.Fields[i-1].AsString := 'Value: ' + IntToStr(i);
  end;
  CDS1.Post;
  NoScrollDBGrid1 := TNoScrollDBGrid.Create(Self);
  NoScrollDBGrid1.Parent := Self;
  NoScrollDBGrid1.Width := 648;
  NoScrollDBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @GuidoG suggested ive tried to give remaining width to one of the columns and it worked. Seems that columns in noscrolldbgrid has to be integer and thats the reason why grid was not filled 100%. Anyway tnx a lot for help.